# Golang - spotify : This request requires user authentication

Tags: go, spotify, spotify-app

I'm writing a bot that takes the name of the music and the artist and adds it to the selected playlist with the [zmb3 Spotify library](https://github.com/zmb3/spotify). Everything works except the section *add music to the playlist* ;

the bot gives me this error: `this request requires user authentication.`
but Spotify token and Spotify secret are valid.

I searched, but I didn't get anything.
Is there anything more needed than Spotify Token and Spotify Secret?
What should I do?

Code :

```
// create spotify client connection and context to connect spotify
    client, ctx := api.SpotifyConnection(SPOTIFYTOKEN, SPOTIFYSECRET)

    // add playlist
    playlist, err := client.GetPlaylist(ctx, PLAYLISTID)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
    }

/* SOME CODES */

if results.Tracks != nil {
            items := results.Tracks.Tracks
            musicID := items[0].ID.String()
            cmd.AddMusic(client, ctx, playlist.ID.String(), musicID)
```

ERROR:

```
2021/12/26 11:06:25 This request requires user authentication.
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at it this way - can you add a track to your playlist while not logged into your account? The same goes for your code. It's not an issue of authenticating to the API with `TOKEN` and `SECRET_KEY`, but you need to introduce user authentication, so that when a user opens your app, they log in and can add tracks to their own playlists.

There is an [Authentication](https://github.com/zmb3/spotify#authentication) section in the zmb3 README that should help:

> You can authenticate using a client credentials flow, but this does not provide any authorization to access a user's private data. For most use cases, you'll want to use the authorization code flow. This package includes an Authenticator type to handle the details for you.